# Drawing UML Activity Diagram - Fetching data decision logic

Tags: uml, diagrams, programming-logic, activity

I have a function to fetch data from remote API and store it in local database. Its logic is:

1. Is network available, if yes proceed to next step, if no show
   error massage.
2. Is app launched for first time, if yes then fetch data from API and store it in local database, if no proceed then proceed to next step.
3. Is the data old or is forced to update, if yes
   then update local database value.
4. If non of the above is applicable then just fetch data from local database.

This is my first time drawing an activity diagram and looking for constructive feedback if I did it correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a flow chart, it's a common practice to ask a question in a box and draw a decision node below of it, with the answers to the question as branch.

But an UML activity diagram is not a flow chart.  The boxes are actions.  Decisions nodes are drawn as diamond,  and the outgoing branches are guarded.  Each guard is between brackets, and the flow is followed only if the guard is true.  This leads to a simpler diagram:

[image]

The horizontal bars represent fork and join nodes. Use this only for parallel actions.  If you meant to show the internals of `Fetch data` you'd proceed with two separate diagrams.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation it's much clearer now.